# Audio signal unstable after 14s using Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I've managed to apply a distiortion effect to an incoming audio signal and with the use of Recorder.js it's even easy to save a recording to a file. This is great because it enables you to build cool effects and easily capture the audio output and mix it in something like Audacity.

However, the signal seems to become unstable after some time, at around 14 seconds. The low frequencies drop and sort of a digitally flanger comes along. The volume also drops and jumps, it becomes quite chaotic. A slightly distorted bass loop recording going down after about 14 seconds to illustrate this can be listened to [here](http://zzp-online-marketing.nl/js-portfolio/audio-manip/distorted-bass-loop.wav).

Recording doesn't seem to be the problem. When I just activate the live stream and monitor the signal I can see/hear the same thing happen when the stream has been going for about 14 seconds.

My first thought is that buffers might be running out after a while?

The app (only works in Chrome for now) in the making that I'm making these recordings with:

http://zzp-online-marketing.nl/js-portfolio/audio-manip/liveOutput.html

It makes use of the createScriptProcessor method, which I understood can cause some trouble. I know it adds a lot of latency, but might it affect the quality of a recording over a relatively longer period?

I'm running this on Windows 8.1 using Chrome 40.0.2214.91 m

Edit: This is the code at its most stripped down that is causing the issue. It's really just connecting soundcard input to destination output.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Distortion effect debug</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();
var liveSource;

navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                           navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                           navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                           navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true, video:false }, function(stream) {
    liveSource = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    liveSource.connect(context.destination);
}, function(err){alert(err);});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sincerely,
Lucas

Comment: Is there any chance you're playing that audio twice?  I don't hear a buffer problem, it sounds to me like phasing.

Comment: Indeed, it does sound like phasing. Well, I'm not playing it back twice intentionally. Perhaps an event retrigger problem that's getting stuck? Although it would still be strange that it only occurs after a certain time.

Comment: It sounds like your sound is on a loop and this problem begins on a later loop.  If that's not the case then that might indicate the sound starting twice at the same time and drifting... which would be really bizarre.

Comment: I've done some further testing. It's not in the createScriptProcessor node, because when I bypass it the problem persists. I'm checking to see if the stream is opened more than once initially with some console.log commands, but it seems to open only once. It's not my own input channel, because when I record in Audacity this problem doesn't occur.
I've tried disabling the recorderjs library, doesn't affect it. The problem seems to boil down to the getUserMedia method. Would it be possible the createUserMedia stream fires more than once on initiation?

Comment: Can you create the smallest code possible to reproduce the issue and add it to your question?

Comment: Can you narrow the problem down further?  I suspect this is going to be an issue with your sound hardware or something related.  Try just playing back file through a node without using getUserMedia.  Next, try recording to a file from getUserMedia while *not* playing back.  And, is your source mono or stereo?  Any stereo to mono conversions happening?